# Show that in MSO can't be express of equality of cardinalities

Tags: logic

> I try to prove that in MSO we can't define equality of two
>   cardinalities of structure. For example number of nodes in two graphs
>   can't be expressed.

My only tool to do this is theorem:

```
Language is regular iff it can be defined in MSO
```

So look please at my trial and try to check it:
We know that language of words such that number of symbol $a$ is equal to number of symbol $b$ is irregular.  We get arbitrary word and construct two graphs - both without edges - only requirement is that number of $a$ is number of nodes and number of $b$ is equal to number in second graph.

Then we assume that there exists formula stated in content of task and we are able to define irregular language. Contradiction.

I know that it is not formal, but I can't do it better.

**Edit**
After suggestion answerer:
$$\phi(X,Y) \leftrightarrow|X|=|Y|$$
$$\exists_X\exists_Y[\phi(X,Y) \wedge (\forall_x (P_a(x)\to x\in X)) \wedge (\forall_x (P_b(y)\to y\in Y)\wedge (\forall_x (x\in X \vee x\in Y))] $$

$P_a(x)$ means that at position $x$ there is a symbol $a$.
I managed (I believe) define language with equal number of symbol $a$ and symbol $b$.

Comment: I think both of your $\to$ should be $\leftrightarrow$, and one of your $\forall x$ should be $\forall y$, but otherwise this looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the right direction to go in.

To make it less handvawy, you should explain exactly how, given a formula $\varphi(X,Y)$ which expresses that $X$ and $Y$ are equinumerous sets, you would construct a formula that recognizes the language $\{\mathtt a^n\mathtt b^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: I edited. Look again, please :)

Comment: @HaskellFun: I don't see any edit.

Comment: You should it now, @Henning Makholm